# java-An unexpected error has been detected by HotSpot Virtual Machine?what is the solution

Tags: java, swing

An unexpected error has been detected by HotSpot Virtual Machine:

EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6d6cf45b, pid=1800, tid=2824

Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (1.5.0_11-b03 mixed mode, sharing)
 Problematic frame:
 V  [jvm.dll+0x8f45b]

An error report file with more information is saved as hs_err_pid1800.log

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp

failed to load library dbtool9.dll...

---

Actually it was working fine with Windows Xp,but when  i put same code in Windows 7 envirinment,its giving avove exception,can anybody pls help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Windows 7 environment is 64-bit and the native library `dbtool9.dll` is 32-bit, you might get that. It's the first thing I'd check. Even if that's not the problem, look for a Win7 compatible version.

---

Elaboration: I assume the DLL `dbtool9.dll` came with the java code you are trying to run. The developer of the code provided or wrote this DLL. Go the the developer's site (or cubicle or what have you), and get a Win 7 compatible version.

Comment: look for a Win7 compatible version----can you please ellaborate,because i am new to java

Comment: [Solved]Solution for this question,Fatal error occured due to Database server was not found,and 'failed to load library dbtool9' reason is code changed to load new dbtool12 which is located at sybase12 root directory.